# Why is this extension not working offline? (code included)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I created an extension (see code below) and I added it to google chrome via "load unpacked extension". I then opened it and used it before shutting down the web server (it's an internal server). When I click to use the app, it just hangs while "requesting." How do I force it to use the app offline and locally only?

I even unplugged the ethernet from the computer (no wifi) and all the other extensions greyed out but mine stayed in color, but when I clicked on it it threw the error:

`The app is currently unreachable.`

Why?

**manifest.js**

```
{
    "name": "Test App",
    "description": "Something",
    "version": "0.0.0.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "*://192.168.1.100/chrome/app/"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "http://192.168.1.100/chrome/app/"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "permissions": [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        loaded
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are two different types of manifest files and you need both (**and** google's documentation never mentions this!).

The first manifest is the chrome app manifest.json. I have that in the code above. While this manifest file purports to tell Chrome what files/urls the app lives at and should be cached (for offline availability), it **does not**. This is handled by a ".manifest" file that lives on the hosting server and must be a file of type "text/manifest". Below are the steps to get this working to make your Chrome app work offline:

**Add the mime type "text/manifest" to your server**

(In Apache, you can add the following to httpd.conf or .htaccess):

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

*It does not need to be named ".manifest" but it's easier to add the mimetype that way*

**Set the manifest linked to in your index.html to point to *that* manifest and not the manifest.json:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="mymanifest.manifest">
```

**Create the manifest file**

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# These are the files that will be cached and available offline
# Their paths are relative to the manifest file
# These files will all load from AppCache and NOT from the server, BUT
# if you want to update them, simply change the manifest file and the browser
# will redownload them
CACHE:
index.html
icon.png

# This would be files that are not cached but live only online
NETWORK:

# Files that are used if any other files cannot be loaded
# example:
#       someimage.png fallbackimage.png
FALLBACK:
```

That's it. Once the user has visited the app online once, Chrome will properly cache everything and it will be available offline.